# how to show PNG images in Toolbar of a WTL application

Tags: png, toolbar, wtl

I have an legacy WTL application where I want to show png images in a toolbar using CToolBarCtrl http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tf5d6ca2(v=vs.80).aspx class. As of now BMP images are shown in the toolbar (by calling LoadToolBar function and making toolbar available in  the resource).

I want to modify it to use PNG images. I have tried using CToolBarCtrl class to load png images but went in vain. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: What's wrong with BMP? Especially if there is no support for PNG where you are trying to mount the images. Or, you can load PNG, convert in-memory, and pass them to the toolbar as bitmaps.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.viksoe.dk/code/photothing.htm) is an example of converting PNG to HBITMAP:

```
#include <gdiplus.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "gdiplus.lib")


ATLINLINE HBITMAP AtlLoadGdiplusImage(ATL::_U_STRINGorID bitmap, ATL::_U_STRINGorID type = (UINT) 0)
{
   USES_CONVERSION;
   static bool s_bInitied = false;
   if( !s_bInitied ) {
      s_bInitied = true;
      Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupInput gsi;
      Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupOutput gso;
      ULONG uToken = 0;
      Gdiplus::GdiplusStartup(&uToken, &gsi, &gso);
   }
   Gdiplus::Bitmap* pBitmap = NULL;
   if( HIWORD(bitmap.m_lpstr) != NULL ) {
      // Load from filename
      pBitmap = new Gdiplus::Bitmap(T2CW(bitmap.m_lpstr)); 
   }
   else if( type.m_lpstr != NULL && type.m_lpstr != RT_BITMAP ) {
      // Loading PNG, JPG resources etc
      WTL::CResource res;
      if( !res.Load(type, bitmap) ) return NULL;
      DWORD dwSize = res.GetSize();
      HANDLE hMemory = ::GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, dwSize);
      if( hMemory == NULL ) return NULL;
      ::memcpy(::GlobalLock(hMemory), res.Lock(), dwSize);
      ::GlobalUnlock(hMemory);
      IStream* pStream = NULL; 
      if( FAILED( ::CreateStreamOnHGlobal(hMemory, TRUE, &pStream) ) ) {
         ::GlobalFree(hMemory);
         return FALSE;
      }
      pBitmap = new Gdiplus::Bitmap(pStream);
      pStream->Release();
   }
   else {
      // This only loads BMP resources
      pBitmap = new Gdiplus::Bitmap(_Module.GetResourceInstance(), (LPCWSTR) (UINT) bitmap.m_lpstr);
   }
   if( pBitmap == NULL ) return NULL;
   HBITMAP hBitmap = NULL;
   pBitmap->GetHBITMAP(NULL, &hBitmap); 
   delete pBitmap;
   return hBitmap;
}
```